# Auto click on sumbit or onclick

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

how to fire submit button click automatically on page load..

```
<form id="loginForm" name="loginForm" method="post" action="http://www.streamuj.tv/login">
                    <input type="text" name="username" value="user" size="22" tabindex="3" id="name" class="logintext">
                    <input name="password" type="password" value="pass" class="logintext" id="password" tabindex="4" size="22">
                    <input type="submit" name="action_login" value="Spustit zdarma" onclick="return foo();" />  
                </form>
```

Comment: What do you mean by auto-click on submit?

Comment: then why do you need a form and submit button?

Comment: When a person enters the current site , so I need to make him automatically login on the web stream ( without without leaving the current web) , with pre-defined username and password so that he can watch videos for free .. Submit button will be hidden

Answer (score 0):

Add an id to the submit button and fire the click using `click()`.

an example would be like

```
<input type="submit" id="my_btn" name="action_login" value="Spustit zdarma" onclick="return foo();" />
```

and fire the click in onload() as below

```
document.getElementById("my_btn").click();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="button" name="action_login" value="Spustit zdarma" onclick="foo(this.form);" />  //pass your form parameter to your function.

   <script type="text/javascript">
        function foo(form) {
  form.submit();   //submit your form
        }
    </script>
```

So your form will be submitted.

Answer (score 0):

insert below in your <head>..</head>

```
<head>
    <!--.... your other code here ... -->

    <script src="jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>

    <script language="javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('form').submit();
    });
    </script>
</head>
```

The code inside $(function() {  ...  }); will automatic run after page is loaded.

Answer (score -1):

```
<form id="loginForm" name="loginForm" method="post" action="http://www.streamuj.tv/login">
    <input type="text" name="username" value="user" size="22" tabindex="3" id="name" class="logintext">
    <input name="password" type="password" value="pass" class="logintext" id="password" tabindex="4" size="22">
    <input type="submit" name="action_login" value="Spustit zdarma" onclick="return foo();" />  
</form> 


<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $( "#loginForm" ).submit();
    });
</script>
```